# I cannot DM users with discord.js bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to build a mail bot in discord.js 
Here is the code so far 
`

```
client.on('message', message=> {
  var input = message.toString().replace("+send ","").split(",");
  const mail = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    mail.setColor('#ff0044')
    mail.setTitle(input[1])
    mail.setAuthor(message.author.username)
    mail.setDescription(input[2])
    mail.setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
    mail.setFooter('Send messages with "+send id,subject,content"');
  client.users.cache.get(input[0]).send(mail);
});
```

`
When the command is sent, it sends the mail but returns this error

> `client.users.cache.get(input[0]).send(mail); TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/VladMail/index.js:18:35) at Client.emit (events.js:315:20) at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12) at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/VladMail/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14) at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/VladMail/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/VladMail/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31) at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/VladMail/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22) at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/VladMail/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10) at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/VladMail/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)`

Why does it return this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `client.users.cache.get(input[0])` returns undefined.

When you try to get it,  check what it is returning to make sure it isn't undefined.

Something like this:

```js
let user = client.users.cache.get(input[0]);
console.log(user);
if(user){
  user.send(mail);
}
```

Comment: I see. I just joined stackoverflow yesterday so I'm new to this